# How to triple boot windows 7, ubuntu 14.04, and ubuntu 14.10 (keeping windows loader if possible)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader, mbr

I want to be able to play around with drivers and updates without
putting my primary work in danger so I want to add ubuntu 14.10 to the
possible OSes I can boot into.

I already have windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 installed and use the
windows bootloader as my primary.

I reduced the size of my last partition and made room for the third OS
(ubuntu 14.10). Booted from my usbstick and installed ubuntu 14.10
using "something else" as an option.  So my partitions (viewed from
the 14.04 system, but after the install) look like this:

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB   523MB   primary   ntfs            boot     /dev/sda1
 2      524MB   211GB   210GB   primary   ntfs                     /dev/sda2        /mnt/windows
 3      211GB   1000GB  790GB   extended                    
 5      211GB   211GB   599MB   logical   ext4                     /dev/sda5        /boot
 6      211GB   261GB   50.0GB  logical   ext4                     /dev/sda6        /
 7      261GB   361GB   100GB   logical   ext4                     /dev/sda7        home
 8      361GB   385GB   24.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)           /dev/sda8
 9      385GB   922GB   536GB   logical   ext4                     /dev/sda9        /mnt/shared
10      922GB   923GB   999MB   logical   ext4                     /dev/sda10
11      923GB   943GB   20.0GB  logical   ext4                     /dev/sda11
12      943GB   1000GB  57.6GB  logical   ext4                     /dev/sda12
```

I went back into windows and ran EasyBCD to add a new entry to the
windows boot loader.  I selected the equivalent of /dev/sda10.  When I
restart the machine I can select the third OS (Ubuntu 14.10), but it
brings me to my previously installed 14.04 OS.

If I look at /dev/sda10,11, and 12 (they are mounted under /media/...)
it looks like sda10 has a grub folder and the files I would expect,
sda11 has the installed OS, etc.

How should I proceed?

Can I edit the grub2 from 14.04 to add an option to select the 14.10
OS?  Do I have to start over?

Info from boot-info can be found at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10623335/

Comment: Are you trying to use one /boot? That will not work. Better with most systems not to have a /boot partition anyway. And if you have a shared data partition(s) then you do not need /home as a separate partition. May be best to see details. Post link to Summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I added a /boot (sda5) for 14.04 and have one for 14.10 (sda11).  Or, at least that what I tried to do.  In any case, I added a link to the summary report above in my question.

Comment: In your 14.04 install run `sudo update-grub` That will add the entried for the new install. I do not know nor suggest EasyBCD. It uses the very old grub4dos and forces you to install grub to a partition. Grub2 does not fit into a partition and it converts to blocklists or hard coded addresses which are unreliable. Make sure you have a working live installer to repair grub on grub updates.  You can create manual entries to boot the partition which saves having to update grub in first install when second install updates. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment offered by @oldfred, I ran `update-grub` from within the 14.04 system.  It automatically added entries for the 14.10 system.  So, I boot using windows MBR and select 14.04, then from the grub screen I pick wither 14.04 or 14.10.

The one gotcha was that update-grub was not in my path.  I ended up having to install the `grub2-common` package and then run it directly, e.g., `sudo /usr/sbin/update-grub`